# android spinner change the background color for specific items

Tags: java, android, spinner

i have a spinner , i want to change the background color for specific items. i mean if the object is named: country and if it have value `section=true` so the item of spinner will have background `color = blue`.

```
@Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 final kamcoReportType report = values.get(position);
  if (convertView == null) {
    Context mContext = this.getContext();
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    if (report.isSection())
       tv.setBackgroundColor=blue  //what ever
```

how can i do that.

Comment: `tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` ?

Comment: Sry my question was Ambiguous, im not asking about how to st background color, mu problem is how to access every item of arraylist in getView() method to vhange the color according to issection value. Plz note that the code above is not working

Comment: Then you need to explain *how* the code is not working.

Comment: First getview() method work for spinner before expand it, but getdropdownview() works for displaying item when expand the spinner, note that i put same code in method getdropdownview() so the problem is the spinner does not expand any more when click:( did you have a code to use in getdropdownview mthod for this goal??

Comment: `getView()` should work when you open and view the spinner items. Does `getView()` not run when you click to expand the spinner items? I assume you are using a Custom Adapter?

Comment: Yes the spinner does not expand when click, so did you mean that i need to delete the method getdropdownview()?? Getview() is enough ?

Comment: Yes, `getView()` should be enough

Comment: @Amalo , I've read your comment and updated my answer. Could you check if that works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `getView()` method you can do:

```
        if (yourCondition) {
            tv.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        }
```

This should do the trick.

@UPDATE

If I got you right, you want to get the current item on your `getView()` method, right?

I assume your adapter is extending `ArrayAdapter<T>`. If this is the case, you can get your items using ArrayAdapter `getItem(position)` method and test it like:

```
if ((getItem(position)).isSection()) { }
```

Inside your `getView()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sry my question was Ambiguous, im not asking about how to st background color, mu problem is how to access every item of arraylist in getView() method to vhange the color according to issection value. Plz note that the code above is not working

Comment: @Amalo I've updated my answer. See if it works. Let me know if I can help with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (report.isSection())
   tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0D47A1"));
```

Comment: Sry my question was Ambiguous, im not asking about how to st background color, mu problem is how to access every item of arraylist in getView() method to vhange the color according to issection value. Plz note that the code above is not working

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I understood that you want to access the item of the list. Well here is how you can do that:

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {
     final kamcoReportType report = values.get(position);
     if (convertView == null) {
         Context mContext = this.getContext();
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         TextView tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
         if (report.isSection())
         tv.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
     //here is how will you access your list: let say, your data list name is "itemList"

        item=itemList.get(position);//it will return the item from that list



}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining *how* this solves the problem and how it is different from other answers? Also, where did `item` and `itemList` come from and how is that line helping?

Comment: Do I need to define getDropDownView() method ?

Comment: You want to access the every item of the array list. itemList= your arraylist and item= for item for specific location.